# Voltage drop and power dissipation

Tags: electric-circuits

Let us consider a circuit consisting of a constant voltage source and various circuit elements with a load resistor. There is a voltage drop across the load. So we can calculate the power dissipated by the load by using the formula P=(Voltage drop)*(current). Let us increase the resistance of the load by keeping other circuit elements fixed. Then there is a larger voltage drop across the load and smaller current in the circuit. Now here is my confusion. What happens to the power dissipated by the load after this change? If I write P=(I^2)R then power decreases, but if I write P=(V^2)/R then power increases. Is something wrong in my explanation?

Comment: Try re-writing those equations with "before" and "after" subscripts: $P_1=\frac{{V_1}^2}{R_1}={I_1}^2R_1$, and $P_2=\frac{{V_2}^2}{R_2}={I_2}^2R_2$. Your question makes it seem as if you expect that $I_1\ne{}I_2$ and $V_1\ne{}V_2$, but maybe you have forgotten to account for the reason behind those changes, namely that $R_1\ne{}R_2$.

Comment: @BobD, $P=IV$ isn't just for resistors. That law is true for _any_ two-terminal component.

Comment: @ThePhoton The OP is talking about power dissipation. Power is only dissipated in resistance. If you just look at rms voltage and current without information on the power factor, you are only sure of reading apparent power.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The OP is talking about power dissipation. Power is only dissipated in resistance. If you just look at rms voltage and current without information on the power factor, you are only sure of reading apparent power.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oops, I didn't notice the OP mention a constant (DC) voltage source . I deleted my comment.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Oops, I didn't notice the OP mention a constant (DC) voltage source . I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I write P=(I^2)R then power decreases, but if I write P=(V^2)/R
> then power increases. Is something wrong in my explanation?

Yes, you're missing the fact that the voltage across and current through aren't independent of the resistance.

For simplicity, assume that the Thevenin equivalent circuit of the source is an ideal DC voltage source $V_{th}$ in series with an ideal Thevenin resistance $R_{th}$.

The voltage $V_L$ across the load resistance $R_L$ is then

$$V_L =  V_{th}\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_{th}}$$

The power dissipated by the load is then

$$P_L = \frac{V_L^2}{R_L} = V^2_{th}\frac{R_L}{(R_L+R_{th})^2}$$

If you stare at this a bit, you'll see that the power goes to zero for both $R_L=0$ and $R_L\rightarrow\infty$

Thus, there is a *maximum* for the power dissipated which is the case for $R_L = R_{th}$ (you should try to show this).

So, if $R_L$ is initially less than (greater than) $R_{th}$, then increasing $R_L$ will result in more (less) power dissipated.

For completeness, solve for the current through

$$I_L = \frac{V_{th}}{R_L+R_{th}}$$

and then

$$P_L = I_L^2R_L = V^2_{th}\frac{R_L}{(R_L+R_{th})^2}$$

which is the same expression found using the voltage across.